# How do I add JPanels, created by methods, to cardLayout.add();

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

below is my user class for guiFrames. I want a class that creates several JFrames with methods and pass those methods into cardLayout. The reason for this is each JFrame will be have different buttons displayed depending on what the user has selected.

So, I thought I would create methods for the individual panels and depending on the parameter passed have different buttons displayed. I need the panels to be displayed in a cardLayout. But I am unable to pass the pass the methods into the cardLayout.add(); because it says the method type is invalid. So I tried to make the method return a Component but its not working out. Help please.

```
        import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class guiFrames extends JFrame{

  public guiFrames(){
  }

  public Component inputFrame(){
    JFrame inputFrame = new JFrame("Input");

    JPanel inputPnl = new JPanel();
    inputPnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

    JLabel loginLbl = new JLabel("Login");
    inputPnl.add(loginLbl);
    JTextField loginTxt = new JTextField();
    inputPnl.add(loginTxt);
    JLabel pwLbl = new JLabel("Password");
    inputPnl.add(pwLbl);
    JTextField pwTxt = new JTextField();
    inputPnl.add(pwTxt);

    JPanel buttonPnl = new JPanel();
    buttonPnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 1,5));

    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    buttonPnl.add(submit);
    JButton output = new JButton("Output");
    buttonPnl.add(output);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    container.add(inputPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    container.add(buttonPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    inputFrame.add(container);
    inputFrame.pack();
    inputFrame.setVisible(true);
    inputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    return;
  }

  public void cardView(){
        JFrame cardFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel cardGUI = new JPanel();
        CardLayout cards = new CardLayout();
        cardGUI.setLayout(cards);
        cardGUI.add(inputFrame(), "first");

        cardFrame.add(cardGUI, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cardFrame.pack();
        cardFrame.setVisible(true);
        cardFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(cardFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: How many JFrames are you wanting to create? Already I see two too many in your code above. You only need one.

Comment: well I want two windows in a card layout view. one window for inputing info and the second for output the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of inputFrame() you aren't returning anything. You need to return the inputFrame, like this:

```
return inputFrame;
```

Hope that helps.